# Delphi has something like javascript "template literals"?

Tags: delphi

[Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) are string literals allowing use multi-line strings, eg.:

```
const MYSTRING = `string text line 1
                  string text line 2
                  string text line 3`;
```

on Delphi my actual approach is:

```
const MYSTRING = 'string text line 1 '+
                 'string text line 2 '+
                 'string text line 3';
```

has Delphi something like javascript "template literals"?

Comment: No. There is no such thing.

Comment: If you want, you can do this ` = 'string line 1 ' + #13#10 + 'string line 2 '` etc.

Comment: What said above plus note that you can also use sLineBreak which is easier to remember (but it is basically a #13#10)

Comment: @Alberto, true, except that it's platform dependent.

Comment: @Victoria: it makes code using it platform *independent*, though. On POSIX, it is a simple #10, on Windows, it is #13#10. So whatever platform you write for, it always produces the correct linebreak.

Comment: @Rudy, yes. I agreed with using `sLineBreak`. Disagreed with that _"it's basically a #13#10"_.

Comment: @Victoria: ah, OK. That was ambiguous, though. ;-)

Comment: @Rudy, you're right. My phrasing unit in my brain failed :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such thing in Delphi. Your current approach using the `+` operator is the best you can do.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include variables and values which is the primary use of JS template literals, you can also consider the Format function:

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.SysUtils.Format

Answer (score 0):

There are no multi-code-line constants in Delphi. You can either use the `+` operator to concatenate multiple lines with the **sLineBreak** system constant like this:

```
MYSTRING = 'line 1' + sLineBreak + 'line 2' + sLineBreak + 'line 3';
```

(You can format that across multiple lines if you want) or if you don't need cross-platform code you can do this:

```
MYSTRING = 'line 1'#13#10'line 2'#13#10'line 3';
```

When using literal characters, you don't have to use the + operator.